# Build new joomla Component in Legacy or Native classes?

Tags: joomla, components

I am starting to develop my very first joomla 3 component.

Should I choose legacy or native classes and why?
What about support in the future?

Joomla core components use Legacy classes. Are they gonna be removed in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting Joomla! development right now, my opinion is to start using the legacy classes. From my knowledge, the legacy support will be in the next major release (3.5) as well in the current STS releases (3.1, 3.2).

What is going to happen in the future is rather a thing that will be discussed, software is evolving, so is Joomla.

**You should learn using the legacy classes because:**

- you will find most of the documentation / books / support about them
- core components are build using them (and understanding how core components work, is a key to your success in developing extensions).

**Native classes:**

- are rather poorly documented
- not so many examples (for example just the Joomla installer is using them)
- not so many use them, so getting support might be rather difficult
- it good to have a look at them one you have more experience with Joomla, so that you can understand the benefits
- they don't have the powerful JModel that the legacy classes have, so building CRUD functionality will require more code to write and mentain
- there are no clear rules on how the code should be organised, so this for a beginner may be confusing, not having a pattern to rely on.

Hope this helps.